# EMC Filter and Vintage Electronics

Tags: filter, emc, surge-protection, vintage

Does anyone have any opinions about using an EMC Filter to protect vintage electronics? I'm referring to very sensitive jukeboxes, pinball machines and this kind of stuff.

I have some machines that have been hit by surge, though we have them fairly well protected (fuses, surge suppressors) but still, when power tools or PA systems or similar are powered on the same circuit as my vintage machines, something will blow inside (may it be a lamp or Jones plugs or something).

Obviously I don't know much about this stuff. Just trying to think of ways to protect my machines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMC filter isn't to protect the electronics, rather it used to prevent outputing noise from electronics into the grid, like switching power supply units. Surge suppressor as you mentioned is a good protection, also adding a choke before MOV suppressor will reduce the rate of change of the spike, thus giving the MOV an extra time until it reacts.

Answer (score 0):

Using a EMC filter is a good idea for vintage electronics .The vintage stuff has little or no EMC filtering.This may have been OK when there were fewer electronic devices around.I put EMC parts into old audio stuff when I fix it .The normal EMC parts do little to nail big high energy surges so thats where your MOVs come in .Rule of thumb Movs for solid state and no mov for valve equipment.This is because valves are more robust and the addition of the mov could in fact reduce reliability .Mov failure is not a pretty sight.